# Can I remove the default SSH key of an Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking to lock down security on my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances. I actually manage my beanstalk instances with Chef, and I use that to deploy individual developer SSH keys to the instances.

I no longer need the key that beanstalk put on the server. Can I safely remove it from the authorized keys file? I can't find any documentation from Amazon about whether this will interfere with deployments or changing out Environment Properties.

Comment: It seems weird to use a service that manages your machines and then throw most of it away.  Beanstalk is basically just EC2 with a load balancer and autoscale groups - would it not be easier to do that with Chef instead of a frankenservice?

Comment: The problem is that my company has been running without a `devops` guy for so long, they did everything in beanstalk. They don't want to move away from the comfort of beanstalk just yet, but they want more control out of the instances. It's an interesting in between zone where they rely on the pre-made automation; they want more automation; but aren't willing to invest the resources to rewrite the deployment or monitoring that beanstalk provides. There's only one of me doing this, so it would be a lot for one guy to redo the concept of beanstalk in-house.

Answer (score 5):

If you configured your EC2 key pair using the `EC2KeyName` Elastic Beanstalk configuration option, you can remove it using the AWS CLI:

```sh
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name $ENV \
    --options-to-remove 'Namespace=aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration,OptionName=EC2KeyName'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it **is** safe to remove the key that beanstalk puts on the instance. For testing, I went ahead and removed it on some test environments: one is a NodeJS beanstalk app and another is a Tomcat/Java app.

From my very first login, I ran `lastlog` to see who's logged in. I've truncated the list to isolate the relevant ones:

```
$ lastlog
Username         Port     From             Latest
root             pts/0                     Mon Jun  5 16:27:42 -0400 2017
ec2-user                                   **Never logged in**
xray                                       Thu May 18 03:10:54 -0400 2017
apache                                     **Never logged in**
healthd                                    Thu May 18 03:11:02 -0400 2017
nodejs                                     Thu May 18 03:17:18 -0400 2017
my-custom-user   pts/0    10.10.x.x        Mon Jun  5 16:27:39 -0400 2017
```

I updated an Environment Properties, and even deployed a new version. That `ec2-user` still shows as `**Never logged in**`

It looks like Beanstalk's automation is using a `nodejs` or `tomcat` user, depending on the beanstalk app type, for it's tasks. Here is what I see in `/var/log/secure`:

```
Jun  5 16:53:40 node-name su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nodejs
Jun  5 16:53:54 node-name su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nodejs by (uid=0)
Jun  5 16:53:54 node-name su: pam_lastlog(su:session): unable to open /var/log/btmp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the ssh key pairs from the AWS console (web interface), it's in EC2 -> Network & Security -> Key Pairs, from there you can remove any key pairs you may have created from Elastic Beanstalk CLI.